# Texts about global minima in functionals

Tags: optimization, reference-request, calculus-of-variations, global-optimization

I am doing some numerics where I found the minimal value of a functional that does not satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation associated. I think I am dealing with a minimal value that is not a local extremum. Can someone indicate a textbook or article that introduces the reader to the difficulties involving **global** minima in calculus of variations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, and topic often missing from discussions of optimal control.

Comment: Doing some research, I found that convexity properties on the functionals may be helpful to find global minimum in calculus of variations. Look here: https://math.unice.fr/~auroux/EPU/Optim2.pdf

Comment: I had an optimal control tutorial somewhere that had some good examples where the choice of admissible controls had a big, non obvious impact on the 'optimal' values. But I have been unable to locate it.

Comment: @Pierre If you want some more concrete help, then you will need to give more details about your functional.

Comment: @KBS The references are enough for me, something like copper.hat said. Thank you.

Comment: @Pierre Depending on the type of functionals you have, resources may differ. Things are not in black and white.

Comment: @KBS I am facing a functional with a double integral integrating in a square, whose integrand is a product between one kernel and two protocols. The kernel is positive definite. I am using genetic programming to achieve a protocol that gives the minimal value of this functional. The question I want to answer is to know if I numerically calculate the global minimum it could result in an optimal protocol that is not a minimal extremum. Answering that would give me a tip to know if the numerical technique I am using is robust enough to give me the optimal protocol.

Comment: @Pierre Please update the question with those details as it will improve the chances to get what you want. Also, consider writing this mathematically for clarity.

Comment: Pierre, since there are no answers to your question yet, don't use `Edit` and just refine the whole question. No need to worry about orphaning comments. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo No edit then. I won't change anything more. Something in the line of copper.hat is what I want.

Comment: Pierre, I don't understand how removing the motivation for this question does somehow improve it.